# Как прописать в Repositoryдобавление элементов по id из database?

Tags: java, android, sql, mvvm, room

Реализую архитектуру `mvvm`. В `dao` есть запросы

```
@Query("SELECT * from word_table WHERE parent_id = 0")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();

@Query("SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE parent_id = :id")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords(final int id);
```

Реализовать работу с первым в `Repository` мне удалось. А как прописать `AsyncTask` для 2 запроса из базы данных?.
Сейчас repository выглядит вот так

```
class WordRepository {

private WordDao mWordDao;
private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

WordRepository(Application application) {
    WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mWordDao = db.wordDao();
    mAllWords = mWordDao.getAlphabetizedWords();
}

LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
    return mAllWords;
}

void insert(Word word) {
    new insertAsyncTask(mWordDao).execute(word);
}

private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Word, Void, Void> {

    private WordDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    insertAsyncTask(WordDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Word... params) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Это Spring и Hibernate?

Comment: @Antonio112009, не знаю. Просто изучаю работу с room persistence library

Answer (score 0):

Зачем использовать AsyncTask? Можно пойти двумя путями:

1. Запустить в отдельном потоке через Executors (тогда word должна быть final)

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
...
void insert(final Word word) {
  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                db.wordDao().insert(word);
            }
        });
}
```

2. Воспользоваться "воркерами" https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html

Второй вариант - по сути правильней. В "воркерах" должно работать большинство операций с обработкой информации, в том числе и работа с базой.